# 3D Procedural generation of infinite caves

Tags: 3d, voxel, procedural-generation

How can you generate good looking caves? I have tried 3D simplex noise and 3D perlin noise, but neither give me any results. Depending on how I set it up, I get either slices or just random noise. My main problem is, that it seems all these noise generators are done for specific size (such as 4095x4095), but I need (relatively) infinite, thus I normalize the real coordinates (which are int) via `coord+(2^31)*(1.0/2^32)*4095`, but for 3D noise, it just makes the slices. If I do not do that, I get just random noise (even with just one octave). Which algorithm and how do you generate random caves in 3D?

Comment: have you look at cellular automaton ?

Comment: it has to be done independently as portion of map is generated

Answer (score 0):

You can use perlin worms. ([this](http://libnoise.sourceforge.net/examples/worms/) might help)